# why async task send ambigous filename?

Tags: android

when i select first video then async task send coreect file name with correct progress value but when select video one by one then async task send ambigous filename. i.e. second video comes with first video filename and first video progressor count, third video comes with first or second video filename and first or second video progressor count and so on, why?

```
MainActivity.java
-------------------
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_VIDEO = 0x100;
    
    private ArrayList<UploadModel> uploadModels;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
    private UploadAdapter uploadAdapter;
    private Activity activity;
    private List<String> mPath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        activity = this;
        uploadModels = new ArrayList<>();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);  // put adding from bottom
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
        uploadAdapter = new UploadAdapter(uploadModels);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(uploadAdapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivityFromGallery();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startActivityFromGallery() {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("video/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_VIDEO);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(photoPickerIntent, "Select Picture"), REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_VIDEO);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult() called with: requestCode = [" + requestCode + "], resultCode = [" + resultCode + "], data = [" + data + "]");
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_VIDEO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mPath = new ArrayList<>();
            Uri  uri = data.getData();
            mPath.add(getVideoPath(uri, MainActivity.this));
            loadVideo();
        }
    }

    private void loadVideo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "loadImage: " + mPath.size());
        if (mPath != null && mPath.size() > 0) {
            UploadModel messageModel = new UploadModelurl, mPath.get(0), UploadModel.STATUS_UPLOAD);
            uploadAdapter.updateMessage(messageModel);
        }
    }

    public static String getVideoPath(final Uri uri, final Activity activity) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } else
            return null;
    }
 }
 
 UploadAdapter.java
 -----------------------
 public class UploadAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UploadAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<UploadModel> mValues;
   
    public UploadAdapter(List<UploadModel> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.fragment_upload, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);

        if(holder.mItem.getStatus() == UploadModel.STATUS_UPLOADING) {
            holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            File  file = new File(holder.mItem.getLocalUrl());
            holder.mIdView.setText(file.getName());
        }

        if(holder.mItem.getStatus() == UploadModel.STATUS_UPLOAD) {
            holder.mItem.setStatus(UploadModel.STATUS_UPLOADING);
            holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            File  file = new File(holder.mItem.getLocalUrl());
           
            MessageUpload.convertVideo(holder.mItem, new MessageUpload.ProgressListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                   holder.mIdView.setText(file.getName() + " Wait.........");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish(boolean result) {
                    holder.mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mIdView.setText(file.getName() + " finished ");
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgress(float progress, String filename) {
                    holder.mIdView.setText(file.getName() + "  " + progress + " %");
                }
            });
        }else  if(holder.mItem.getStatus() == UploadModel.STATUS_UPLOADED) {
         holder.mIdView.setText(file.getName() + " finished ");
        }
     }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        private final ProgressBar mProgressBar;   // Resolve Issue #52
        public UploadModel mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress);
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
           
        }
    }

    public void updateMessage(UploadModel message) {
        List<UploadModel> messageList = mValues;

        int messagePosition = messageList.indexOf(message);

        if (messagePosition >= 0 && messagePosition < messageList.size()) {
            messageList.set(messagePosition, message);
        } else {
            messageList.add(message);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

MessageUpload.java
-------------------------
public class MessageUpload {

    public UploadMessage convertVideo(UploadModel messageModel, ProgressListener listener) {
        UploadMessage task = new UploadMessage(listener);
        task.execute(messageModel);
        return task;
    }

    public interface ProgressListener {

        void onStart();
        void onFinish(boolean result);
        void onProgress(float progress, String filename);

    }
}

UploadMessage.java
-------------------------
public class UploadMessage extends AsyncTask<UploadModel, Integer, String> {

    private final MessageUpload.ProgressListener mListener;
    private UploadModel messageModel;
    private String filename;
    private long totalSize = 0;


public UploadMessage(MessageUpload.ProgressListener listener) {
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        mListener.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mListener.onProgress(progress[0], filename);

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(UploadModel... params) {
        messageModel = params[0];
        File file = new File(messageModel.getLocalUrl());
        filename = file.getName();
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(messageModel.getUrl());

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new AndroidMultiPartEntity.ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(messageModel.getLocalUrl());

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("file", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server responsetext
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: " + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mListener.onFinish(true);

    }
}
```

Comment: `private ArrayList<UploadModel> uploadModels;` Remove that line.

Comment: `mPath = new ArrayList<>();` Remove that line.

Comment: `loadVideo();` Change to `loadVideo(data.getData());`. Change the function to take an uri parameter. Then continue with that uri.